# ngTable is not showing rows

Tags: ngtable

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/auVpma0kdcC9J8vWKc9f?p=preview) I have an `ngTable` that is supposed to show two rows, instead it shows only the header. What's wrong with this code?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$timeout,NgTableParams) {

      $timeout(function() {

          $scope.data = [ 
            { uid: 'User 1', nm: 'Name 1', ugr: 'Group 1'},
            { uid: 'User 2', nm: 'Name 2', ugr: 'Group 2'}
          ];

          $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({dataset: $scope.data});

    }, 1000);


  $scope.toggleFilter = function (){
     $scope.showFilter = !$scope.showFilter;
  };


});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl" ng-app="app">

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="toggleFilter()">Toggle Filter</a>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="showFilter" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in $data">
                <td title="'User ID'" filter="{ uid: 'text' }" sortable="'uid'" style="width:150px">{{ u.uid }}</td>
                <td title="'Name'" filter="{ nm: 'text' }" sortable="'nm'" style="width:150px">{{ u.nm }}</td>
                <td title="'Group'" filter="{ ugr: 'text'}" sortable="'ugr'" style="width:200px">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct Answer:**

My apologies, I was too hasty in my first answer. My solution fixed it, but it was incorrect.

The real issue is that you need to change 'dataset' to 'data' in the controller, like this (using NgTable v.0.8.3):

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count: 5}, {data: $scope.data});
```

I have also added a count, otherwise, it displays one item at a time.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/plDiFc4CCmrIf5YOeD5M?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: This answer is incorrect, please see the answer marked as "correct".**

It works if you change '$data' to 'data' in the HTML.

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="showFilter" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in data">
                <td title="'User ID'" filter="{ uid: 'text' }" sortable="'uid'" style="width:150px">{{ u.uid }}</td>
                <td title="'Name'" filter="{ nm: 'text' }" sortable="'nm'" style="width:150px">{{ u.nm }}</td>
                <td title="'Group'" filter="{ ugr: 'number'}" sortable="'ugr'" style="width:200px">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WlPVGYjSshLkwbJ78xNO?p=preview

The examples on the NgTable website use v1.0.0-beta.9, so my guess is they are slightly outdated perhaps.

Comment: This does not really fix the issue. Apologies for that. Please see my updated answer below.